# Assign a list of items to a variable and iterate in cursor SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I have a predefined list of items which I want to use in select query.

```
DECLARE @cur_emp CURSOR;
DECLARE @TEST_ID int
DECLARE @TEST_NAME varchar(100)
DECLARE @names table(name varchar(100))

--SET @TEST_NAME = 'Order not timely approved'
insert into @names(name) values ('a')
insert into @names(name) values ('b')

--SET @TEST_NAME = CURSOR FOR (select name from @names)
WHILE EXISTS (select * from @names)
BEGIN
SET @cur_emp= CURSOR FOR (select TEST_ID from CS_TEST_V2 where test_name = @name)
```

Error says: @name is an invalid column name
Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your cursor part. Please try this.

```
DECLARE @TEST_ID INT
DECLARE @TEST_NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @names TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(100))

--SET @TEST_NAME = 'Order not timely approved'
INSERT INTO @names (NAME)
VALUES ('a')

INSERT INTO @names (NAME)
VALUES ('b')

DECLARE cur_emp CURSOR
FOR
SELECT NAME
FROM @names;

OPEN cur_emp

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_emp
INTO @TEST_NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @TEST_ID = (
            SELECT TEST_ID
            FROM CS_TEST_V2
            WHERE test_name = @TEST_NAME
            )

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_emp
    INTO @TEST_NAME
END

CLOSE cur_emp

DEALLOCATE cur_emp
```